# Optimizing activerecord queries for displaying attendees of an event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm currently hacking on an events site and have never had a problem optimizing queries/scaling my db in the past as there was never that much data, but now there's almost a million rows in the db and it's taking ~15,000 m/s to render a feed of events, in particular the partial (within each _event.html.erb) that's really slow is where all the users that youre currently following that are attending that event are displayed. I've looked up a lot of possibilities to improve performance including eager loading, indexing, memcache, etc...but was wondering how this can be rewritten to perform faster? Thank you!

_attending.html.erb

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
        <% @rsvp = Rsvp.where(:voter_id => current_user.following, :event_id => event.id, :status => 'going') %>
        <% if @rsvp.count == 0 %>
            <%= eventcount(event) %> going.
        <% elsif @rsvp.count == 1 %>
            <% if eventcount(event) - 1 == 0 %>
                <% Rsvp.where(:voter_id => current_user.following, :event_id => event.id, :status => 'going')[0..0].each do |f| %>
                    <%= link_to User.find(f.voter_id).name, User.find(f.voter_id).slug %> is going.
                <% end %>
            <% else %>
              <% Rsvp.where(:voter_id => current_user.following, :event_id => event.id, :status => 'going')[0..0].each do |f| %>
                  <%= link_to User.find(f.voter_id).name, User.find(f.voter_id).slug %> and <%= eventcount(event) - 1 %> going.
              <% end %>
            <% end %>
        <% elsif @rsvp.count == 2 %>
            <% if eventcount(event) - 2 == 0 %>
                <% Rsvp.where(:voter_id => current_user.following, :event_id => event.id, :status => 'going')[0..0].each do |f| %>
                    <%= link_to User.find(f.voter_id).name, User.find(f.voter_id).slug %> and
                <% end %>
                <% Rsvp.where(:voter_id => current_user.following, :event_id => event.id, :status => 'going')[1..1].each do |f| %>
                    <%= link_to User.find(f.voter_id).name, User.find(f.voter_id).slug %> are going.
                <% end %>
            <% else %>
              <% Rsvp.where(:voter_id => current_user.following, :event_id => event.id, :status => 'going')[0..0].each do |f| %>
                  <%= link_to User.find(f.voter_id).name, User.find(f.voter_id).slug %>,
              <% end %>
              <% Rsvp.where(:voter_id => current_user.following, :event_id => event.id, :status => 'going')[1..1].each do |f| %>
                  <%= link_to User.find(f.voter_id).name, User.find(f.voter_id).slug %> and <%= eventcount(event) - 2 %> going.
              <% end %>
                <% end %>
        <% elsif @rsvp.count == 3 %>
            <% if eventcount(event) - 3 == 0 %>
                <% Rsvp.where(:voter_id => current_user.following, :event_id => event.id, :status => 'going')[0..0].each do |f| %>
                    <%= link_to User.find(f.voter_id).name, User.find(f.voter_id).slug %>,
                <% end %>
                <% Rsvp.where(:voter_id => current_user.following, :event_id => event.id, :status => 'going')[1..1].each do |f| %>
                    <%= link_to User.find(f.voter_id).name, User.find(f.voter_id).slug %>, and
                <% end %>
                <% Rsvp.where(:voter_id => current_user.following, :event_id => event.id, :status => 'going')[2..2].each do |f| %>
                    <%= link_to User.find(f.voter_id).name, User.find(f.voter_id).slug %> are going.
                <% end %>
            <% else %>
              <% Rsvp.where(:voter_id => current_user.following, :event_id => event.id, :status => 'going')[0..0].each do |f| %>
                  <%= link_to User.find(f.voter_id).name, User.find(f.voter_id).slug %>,
              <% end %>
              <% Rsvp.where(:voter_id => current_user.following, :event_id => event.id, :status => 'going')[1..1].each do |f| %>
                  <%= link_to User.find(f.voter_id).name, User.find(f.voter_id).slug %>,
              <% end %>
              <% Rsvp.where(:voter_id => current_user.following, :event_id => event.id, :status => 'going')[2..2].each do |f| %>
                  <%= link_to User.find(f.voter_id).name, User.find(f.voter_id).slug %> and <%= eventcount(event) - 3 %> are going.
              <% end %>
            <% end %>
            <% end %>
    <% else %>
        <%= eventcount(event) %> going.
    <% end %>
```

Schema for RSVP

```
create_table "rsvps", :force => true do |t|
  t.string    "status"
  t.integer   "event_id"
  t.integer   "voter_id"
  t.string    "voter_name"
  t.string    "voter_type"
  t.timestamp "created_at", :null => false
  t.timestamp "updated_at", :null => false
end

add_index "rsvps", ["voter_id", "voter_type", "event_id"], :name => "fk_one_rsvp_per_user_per_entity", :unique => true
add_index "rsvps", ["voter_id", "voter_type"], :name => "index_rsvps_on_voter_id_and_voter_type"
```

Schema for Relationship

```
create_table "relationships", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer   "follower_id"
  t.integer   "followed_id"
  t.timestamp "created_at",  :null => false
  t.timestamp "updated_at",  :null => false
end

add_index "relationships", ["followed_id"], :name => "index_relationships_on_followed_id"
add_index "relationships", ["follower_id"], :name => "index_relationships_on_follower_id"
```

Relevant part of User model

```
has_many :relationships, :foreign_key => "follower_id",
:dependent => :destroy

has_many :following, :through => :relationships, :source => :followed

has_many :reverse_relationships, :foreign_key => "followed_id",
       :class_name => "Relationship",
       :dependent => :destroy
has_many :followers, :through => :reverse_relationships, :source => :follower
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you have all that logic in the views? You should refactor that down to controllers, models, and even helpers.

Comment: Yeah, that's something I've been really bad about, I plan to do a major clean up to make it more DRY/concatenated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the large db is the RSVP:

You do a very large call to the db in your partial, try to reduce the n call `Rsvp.where(:voter_id => current_user.following, :event_id => event.id, :status => 'going')` only one time, and then working on it in the different cases. This can help a little in performance (every time you call a .where in large db is a complex process if you have a large db). Re-use the variable @rsvp.

Comment: thanks so much for the answer! that ended up being only a small performance improvement, maybe 50-100 m/s. i just started using memcached though and it was an instant 75%+ performance improvement

Comment: yes, you can't gain so much with this improvement, but as you write combining performance improving (e.g. memcached) you can gain a considerable improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Just doing a quick clean up and following what @damoiser said you should refactor your view to something like this.

**_attending.html.erb**

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <% @rsvp = get_rsvps %>
  <% if @rsvp.count == 0 %>
    <%= eventcount(event) %> going.
  <% elsif @rsvp.count == 1 %>
    <% if eventcount(event) - 1 == 0 %>
      <% @rsvp[0..0].each do |f| %>
        <%= link_to User.find(f.voter_id).name, User.find(f.voter_id).slug %> is going.
      <% end %>
    <% else %>
      <% @rsvp[0..0].each do |f| %>
          <%= link_to User.find(f.voter_id).name, User.find(f.voter_id).slug %> and <%= eventcount(event) - 1 %> going.
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% elsif @rsvp.count == 2 %>
    <% if eventcount(event) - 2 == 0 %>
      <% @rsvp[0..0].each do |f| %>
        <%= link_to User.find(f.voter_id).name, User.find(f.voter_id).slug %> and
      <% end %>
      <% @rsvp[1..1].each do |f| %>
        <%= link_to User.find(f.voter_id).name, User.find(f.voter_id).slug %> are going.
      <% end %>
    <% else %>
      <% @rsvp[0..0].each do |f| %>
        <%= link_to User.find(f.voter_id).name, User.find(f.voter_id).slug %>,
      <% end %>
      <% @rsvp[1..1].each do |f| %>
        <%= link_to User.find(f.voter_id).name, User.find(f.voter_id).slug %> and <%= eventcount(event) - 2 %> going.
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% elsif @rsvp.count == 3 %>
    <% if eventcount(event) - 3 == 0 %>
      <% @rsvp[0..0].each do |f| %>
        <%= link_to User.find(f.voter_id).name, User.find(f.voter_id).slug %>,
      <% end %>
      <% @rsvp[1..1].each do |f| %>
        <%= link_to User.find(f.voter_id).name, User.find(f.voter_id).slug %>, and
      <% end %>
      <% @rsvp[2..2].each do |f| %>
          <%= link_to User.find(f.voter_id).name, User.find(f.voter_id).slug %> are going.
      <% end %>
    <% else %>
      <% @rsvp[0..0].each do |f| %>
        <%= link_to User.find(f.voter_id).name, User.find(f.voter_id).slug %>,
      <% end %>
      <% @rsvp[1..1].each do |f| %>
        <%= link_to User.find(f.voter_id).name, User.find(f.voter_id).slug %>,
      <% end %>
      <% @rsvp[2..2].each do |f| %>
        <%= link_to User.find(f.voter_id).name, User.find(f.voter_id).slug %> and <%= eventcount(event) - 3 %> are going.
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= eventcount(event) %> going.
<% end %>
```

You should also have some helper like so:

**some_helper.rb**

```
module SomeHelper
  def get_rsvps
    Rsvp.where(:voter_id => current_user.following, :event_id => event.id, :status => 'going')
  end
end
```

**HUGE NOTE**:
This code is still in no terms good to go. I still think theres a lot of refactoring to be done. Like the [0..0].each and [1..1].each and lot of code duplication on the link_to helpers. But this should get you some performance since you are only doing a call for the rsvps and reusing what you stored in the @rsvp.